# Show product sizes below product in frontend

Tags: magento2

How can I display the sizes, 'size' attribute, in the frontend? Like in the Magento demo store, both color and size are shown under the product, I just want to display the size.

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

**Catalog Input Type for Store Owner:** select `Text swatch` Or `dropdown`

And store property:

**Used in Product Listing**: Select "`Yes`"

Run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: No, I want to display it, not hide. I have set `Use in Product Listing` to `YES` but it doesn't work

Comment: Run command : php bin/magento cache:flush and check again @VirtusO

Comment: I have, also reindexed

Comment: Have you selected : Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: select Text swatch ? @VirtusO

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this step

1. GO to admin >> Store >> Product >> Search "Size" attribute and edit it
2. Make sure your attribute type is either "Text Swatch" Or "Visual Swatch"
3. Click on **Store Front** Tab and Select Yes for "Use is product listing"

[image]